# Incremental modelling of kmeans in pyspark

Tags: k-means, pyspark, online-learning

I have a large dataset and trained the model with kmeans for the first time. I  saved the model and pipeline used . Now again I started collecting data.  After sufficient data is collected using old model and pipeline I want to retrain the model on new collected data in Pyspark

Is it possible to use transfer learning in unsupervised learning algorithms (or clustering) like Kmeans in Pyspark? If so, how it can be done?

Comment: Hi welcome to DS stackexchange. Question is not clear yet, once model is trained with large data why you want to train again on new dataset.?

Comment: once the model is trained i want to save the model, then re-train only on the new data without training on the entire dataset. Basically I want to apply transfer learning on kmeans model I have

Comment: Transfer learning is most associated with deep neural networks because they learn so much that isn't especially task specific. However, there is very interesting work from Google on using transfer learning with Gaussian processes for hyperparameter optimisation. But i dont think we can apply transfer learning in clustering. Retrain will be the best possible approach.

Comment: I think he meant something like online/incremental learning.

Comment: Yes. As you said `Creme` is the answer and shall we mark this as accepted.?

Answer (score 1):

There's dedicated lib for incremental / online learning. It's called `Creme`. You can find it [here](https://github.com/creme-ml/creme). It has `kmeans` implemented, though I don't know how well it's suited for `spark` data sets.

Comment: I'm not asking about online learning. I want to use batch processing and use old model to retrain on new data

Comment: That's basically online learning.